# Access Id from parent activity to fragments in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager

I have faced this issue, maybe there is already the same issue, but I cannot find in this page. So my problem is that I have my activity, which initialize ViewPager and I have 2 fragments in this viewpager.

My Activity:

```
public class ShoppingDetailsActivity extends BaseActivity {

ViewPagerAdapter adapter;

@Bind(R.id.view_pager)
ViewPager viewPager;
@Bind(R.id.pager_tabs)
PagerSlidingTabStrip pagerSlidingTabStrip;

int shop_id;
int id;
int shop_sub_id;
int subId;
int shop_sub_sub_id;
int subSubId;
int shop_detail_id;
int detailId;

public static final String SHOP_ID = "shop_id";
public static final String SHOP_SUB_ID = "shop_sub_id";
public static final String SHOP_SUB_SUB_ID = "shop_sub_sub_id";
public static final String SHOP_DETAIL_ID = "shop_detail_id";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    activityComponent().inject(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_shopping_details);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    pagerSlidingTabStrip.setViewPager(viewPager);

    shop_id = getIntent().getIntExtra(SHOP_ID, id);
    shop_sub_id = getIntent().getIntExtra(SHOP_SUB_ID, subId);
    shop_sub_sub_id = getIntent().getIntExtra(SHOP_SUB_SUB_ID, subSubId);
    shop_detail_id = getIntent().getIntExtra(SHOP_DETAIL_ID, detailId);
}

}
```

My Adapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new InfoAdminFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new ViewAdminFragment();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        return "InfoAdminFragment";
    } else if (position == 1) {
        return "ViewAdminFragment";
    } else {
        return super.getPageTitle(position);
    }
}
}
```

As you can see in My Activity I have a lot of IDs using *getIntent()* and get them successfully, but I also need somehow to pass to my both fragments in ViewPager, how can I make solve this issue?

Comment: You have to pass data to your adapter whatever you want to forward to fragment, check readyandroid answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your code with this one:

```
private int shop_id;
private int shop_sub_id;
private int shop_sub_sub_id;
private int shop_detail_id;

public void setExtraData(int shopId, int shopSubId, shopSubSubId, shopDetailId) {
    this.shop_id = shopId;
    this.shop_sub_id = shopSubId;
    this.shop_sub_sub_id = shopSubSubId;
    this.shop_detail_id = shopDetailId;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new InfoAdminFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new ViewAdminFragment();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    setBundleData(fragment);

    return fragment;
}

public void setBundleData(Fragment fragment){
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("shop_id", shop_id);
    bundle.putInt("shop_sub_id", shop_sub_id);
    bundle.putInt("shop_sub_sub_id", shop_sub_sub_id);
    bundle.putInt("shop_detail_id", shop_detail_id);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
}
```

And in your activity:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    activityComponent().inject(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_shopping_details);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    shop_id = getIntent().getIntExtra(SHOP_ID, id);
    shop_sub_id = getIntent().getIntExtra(SHOP_SUB_ID, subId);
    shop_sub_sub_id = getIntent().getIntExtra(SHOP_SUB_SUB_ID, subSubId);
    shop_detail_id = getIntent().getIntExtra(SHOP_DETAIL_ID, detailId);

    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.setExtraData(shop_id, shop_sub_id, shop_sub_sub_id, shop_detail_id);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    pagerSlidingTabStrip.setViewPager(viewPager);

}
```

In your fragment you can get:

```
getArguments().getInt(/*Key*/, /*Default value*/);
```

like:

```
getArguments().getInt("shop_id", -1);
```

**You can achieve the same above scenario by passing intent rather than single-single values as I am doing here in setExtraData method of adapter.**

Answer (score 2):

Pass the ID's as bundle to `ViewPager` adapter from your activity

```
adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getIntent().getExtras());
```

Modify your `ViewPager` adapter as below

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private Bundle bundle;

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Bundle bundle) {
    super(fm);
    this.bundle = bundle;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new InfoAdminFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new ViewAdminFragment();
            break;
        default:
            fragment = new InfoAdminFragment();
            break;
    }
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;
}

//other code

}
```

And retrieve the bundle in your fragments

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
shopId = bundle.getInt(ShoppingDetailsActivity.SHOP_ID);
```